# incorrect frame using zoom uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have got an `UIScrollView` that contain UIImageView.
I need to zoom my UIImageView.

I'm using method below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView; // my UIImage about I describe here.
}
```

In viewDidLoad method I set frame for my `UIImageView` (e.g. `NSRect: {{110, 180}, {100, 100}}`)

```
NSLog(@"image view frame %@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.imageView.frame]);
```

in this case in log out this value: image view frame `NSRect: {{110, 180}, {100, 100}}`

but when I try to out put frame of imageView after zoom I get new value with a next amount:

**{{9.9999971, 9.9999971}, {100.00001, 100.00001}}**

And I don't understand why I get this value **9.9999971**. What I mean. Yes I know that after zoom we change our coordinate, but I dont understand why we get not a **9.0f** instead **9.9999971** and why not **100.0** instead **100.00001**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented demo code of image zoom which you have mentioned.

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return imgZoom;
  }

I have got value of imageview which I have set in the view did load.

I think you have done some thing wrong.

If you can share more then I can tell you in details.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. So I have two parts where I check value of CGRect UIImageView. So, first - where I output value in viewDidLoad method and on this stage I have correct value of CGRect UIImageView. On next step I do something with zoom method (e.g. increase zoom). Then I want to check new value of CGRect UIImageViwe and on this stage I get strange params e.g. {{9.9999971, 9.9999971}, {100.00001, 100.00001}} and other. But I want to get {{10.0, 10.0}, {100.0, 100.0}} instead.